# Why do symbols disappear from an Inkscape-generated PDF?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, inkscape

I have created this graph in Inkscape

[image]
I save it as pdf_tex

but in my research PDF it looks like this !!!

[image]

Why I dont get the right font, font size, and symbols in my PDF

Comment: The reason to save as pdf_tex is to allow LaTeX to render the font and the symbols, in order to get a more uniform look for all the images in your document. However, if you want the exact font, position, and symbols as in Inkscape itelf, then it is better to save as PDF directly from Inkscape (instead of pdf_tex) and use `\includegraphics` in your LaTeX code.

Comment: @Marijn many thanks, but the image is bigger than the page now !! how to fix that?

Comment: @asmgx you could try to make it smaller :D either in Inkscape, or in LaTeX with `\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{yourfile}`.

Comment: @Marijn perfect.. thanks :)